Несимметричный ЦДА на С#
Нужно реализовать несимметричный ЦДА в приложении Windows Forms.
Сделал это таким образом:
private void PutPixel(float x, float y)
{
    g.DrawRectangle(myPen, x, y, 1, 1);
}
private void asymmetricalCDA(float xn, float yn, float xk, float yk)
{
    float Px = xk - xn;
    float Py = yk - yn;

    float X1 = xn;
    float Y1 = yn;
    PutPixel(X1, Y1);

    while (X1 < xk)
    {
        X1 = X1 + 1.0f;
        Y1 = Y1 + Py / Px;
        PutPixel(X1, Y1);
    }
}

Основная проблема заключается в попытках нарисовать вертикальные отрезки. При попытке нарисовать отрезвок сверху-вниз или снизу-вверх, отрезок генерируется некорректно - получаются пунктиры или отрезок вообще не генерируется.
Хз если что-то не уточнил, напишите пж.

Ну на ноль же нельзя делить...
Сначала выбирайте, по какой координате больше абсолютная разница, и именно по ней делайте +1.0f, а по второй +Py/Px или +Px/Py соответственно

Спасибо большое)

Ещё недосмотрел - нужно учитывать знаки разностей. Например, если Px<0, и единичный шаг будет по иксу, то нужно использовать -1.0f и -Py/Px .
